# Neo4j Java API: widest path algorithm performance issues

Tags: java, algorithm, neo4j, graph-databases

i'm using the neo4j-enterprise edition version 2.1.2 and do have an graph with 229626 nodes and 1667834 relationships. The graph model describes which person knows another person with a given timestamp on the relationship (including identifiers for each person).

I tried to define an algorithm for the widest path problem using the existing dijkstra implementation of the Neo4j Java Core API (embedded mode). Unfortunately it performs very slow. But first let me show you some details of my current implementation:

1. Defining the algorithm with the custom CostEvaluator and PathExpander

   ```
   PathFinder<WeightedPath> finder = GraphAlgoFactory
   .dijkstra(new   TimestampPathExpander(RelationType.KNOWS,
   Direction.BOTH, 1401746400, depth),  new RelationshipCostEvaluator());
   ```

   The number "1401746400" represents the timestamp. Each relationship with smaller or equal to it should be checked. I also introduced a depth to minimize the path length and searching overhead.
2. TimestampPathExpander

   ```
     @Override public Iterable<Relationship> expand(Path path, BranchState<String> state) {
           List<Relationship> results = new ArrayList<Relationship>();

           if(path.length() >= depth) {
           return results;
           }

           for (Relationship r : path.endNode().getRelationships(relationshipType,
           direction)) {
               // Traverse only relations for the given timestamp
               long relationTime = (long) r.getProperty("timestamp");
               if (relationTime <= timestamp) {
                results.add(r);
               }
       }
       return results;
   }
   ```

   The expander is really straight forward. Just looking at the relationship timestamp and adding the nodes to the result list. In case the resulting path has reached the max depth, no other nodes are added to it.
3. Custom CostEvaluator

   ```
   @Override
   public Double getCost(Relationship relationship, Direction direction) {
      double measure = significance.edgeStrength(relationship);
      return measure > 0 ? Double.MAX_VALUE - measure : 0;
   }
   ```

The measure is used as capacity value and is calculated according to a metric including the start and end node, as well as the relationship of both. Because dijkstra can't handle negative edge weights I just subtract from a big amount (Double.Max_value) the measure and achieving thereby that big values are being interpreted "cheaper". Returning zero is the corner case which should not be touched.

This is how I warm up my cache:

```
    for ( Node n : GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodes() ) {
        n.getPropertyKeys();
        for ( Relationship relationship : n.getRelationships() ) {
            Node start = relationship.getStartNode();
        }
    }
```

I'm also using the soft cache and the following graph.db properties with an index on the identifier of the nodes and the start and end of the relations:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=3G
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=2G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=100M

neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=500M

use_memory_mapped_buffers=true
```

Here are some performance measures always with the warmed up cache:

```
Cache warmup...    |   Cache warmup...
1742 ms            |   30056 ms
1106 ms            |   22696 ms
970 ms             |   24406 ms
849 ms             |   22842 ms
Angela Merkel      |   Angela Merkel
0.3                |   0.3
CDU                |   Wladimir Putin
```

Around 3 seconds for just a hop. That's pretty much. Are there some tricks I don't know to improve these results? Maybe I did something wrong? Hope someone could help.

Regards.

Comment: Jesus.  An acceptably fast implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm takes about as much code as your "expander."  You've got 200k nodes and just over a million edges; there's no reason not to offload the graph and do the shortest paths directly.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you, but I need the max capacity path between two nodes if this path is shorter or equal to 4. I'm interested in an interesting path which are expressed through the significance measure.  The numbers expresses how strongly the nodes are associated and I want to retrieve interesting routes. So the algorithm should take that path where the significance will be maximized. But if the route is longer than 4 hops I can just take the shortest path. I thought neo4j can handle such big graphs and traversals.

Comment: It's not even a big graph.    Is significance additive or do you want to maximise the minimum significance along the path or what?  (If it's multiplicative, then its logarithm is additive.  If you're doing min-max, you're looking for Prim's algorithm, which is...essentially the same as Dijkstra.)

Comment: The significance is additive. It expresses how strongly connected two nodes are. By searching for a path where the cumulative significance is maximized I can retrieve a path containing only "interesting" nodes regarding a start node and an end node. The significance measure is something like this [1]

Comment: [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information

Comment: Yeah, then just pull the graph out of the database and do Dijkstra like your textbook tells you.  With a priority queue and all.

Comment: Then I don't need a GraphDatabase such as Neo4j anymore. I will try to use the JUNG Framework with entities and relationships in memory. Maybe I can replace these afterwards with an efficient key-value store. But for now i'm done with neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

What is your system setup?

It seems that your mmio config is way too high and consumes all your heap so leaving no heap for Neo4j's algorithm? Ho much memory do you have in total? I think for your graph 10M for the nodes and 50M for the relationships is more than good enough. Your warmup should also access the timestamp / cost properties so that they are loaded.

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=10M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=0M

# remove both
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=500M
```

Can you also share the code of this method? `significance.edgeStrength(relationship);` I wonder if your cost of 0 will affect the algorithm aversely, as a smaller cost will cause more paths to be considered and if the cost doesn't vary (all +0) then they are equally weighted ...

I would only construct an ArrayList if your length is less than your limit, otherwise just return `Collections.emptyList();`